# Вернуть часть строки кроме

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем добрый день! Как правильно составить регулярку, пробовал, но не получается то, что нужно. Есть много текста вида

"rwrwerw rewrwr http://www.site1.com rewrwrw rewrewrwe needword rewrewrewrwe fdsfasfafdsa http://www.site2.com fdsafsafdsafsaf rewrewrew rewrewrewrwe fdsfasfafdsa http://www.site3.com fdsafsafdsafsaf rewrewrew"

Как можно разбить текст разделителем по слову "http://www.site.com" регуляркой с сохранением содержимого регулярки. Или найти/вернуть куски текста "http://www.site.com fdsfsaf fdsfsaf" включающие http://www.site.com в начале, но исключающие следующий http://www.site.com. Следующий http://www.site.com будет со своим последующим текстом. Перепробовал кучу вариантов, но что-то не получается. Такой вариант вроде подходит

~((?:http|https)://.*?)(?=[\s]+).*?(?=(?:http|https))~is

Но preg_match_all возвращает подстроки с site1 и site2, а блок текста с site3 не возвращает

Comment: Благодарю за ваши профессиональные ответы! Они очень мне помогли! Я еще не раз буду изучать их) Жаль нельзя отметить два ответа. Проголосовал за оба, когда рейтинг станет 15, голоса добавятся. Ответ Эдуарда четко решает поставленный вопрос с сохранением последнего элемента (понял почему у меня не включался третий блок с http). Ответ PhoEn-X очень интересен и полезен. Он показывает как можно найденные данные вернуть раздельно и с учетом последнего блока. Но извиняюсь, так, как я этого не указал в вопросе думаю правильным будет выбрать решением ответ Эдуарда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = 'rwrwerw rewrwr http://www.site1.com rewrwrw rewrewrwe needword rewrewrewrwe fdsfasfafdsa http://www.site2.com fdsafsafdsafsaf rewrewrew rewrewrewrwe fdsfasfafdsa http://www.site3.com fdsafsafdsafsaf rewrewrew';

$patt = '~https?://.+?(?=https?|$)~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'http://www.site1.com rewrwrw rewrewrwe needword rewrewrewrwe fdsfasfafdsa ' (length=74)
      1 => string 'http://www.site2.com fdsafsafdsafsaf rewrewrew rewrewrewrwe fdsfasfafdsa ' (length=73)
      2 => string 'http://www.site3.com fdsafsafdsafsaf rewrewrew' (length=46)
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, не самая красивая реализация, но

`(https?:\/\/.+?)\s+((?:.(?!https?:\/\/))*)`

- `(https?:\/\/.+?)` адрес сайта
- `((?:.(?!https?:\/\/))*)` текст после адреса до `http` или `https` (исключая последний пробел)